# Encrypt clients files and shares

Tags: encryption, secret-sharing

I have to encrypt data (files) of client on server side and only the client can read theses files (admin can't see name and content of file).

To resolve this, I have the idea to just use something client have and the admin doesn't, his password to generate a cipher key, this idea is simple.

But I have a constraint for this project, every user can share file(s) with other users (read-only). So the first idea can't be use here.

After some reflexion and discussion, I had this idea:

When user add a file, the server:

1. generate random cipher key
2. encrypt file/filename with this key
3. encrypt this cipher key(1) with derivate key of user password
4. store this(3) in **files_keys** table

When user want to share a file:

1. the user (who want to share) sent the derivate key of his password, id of file to the server
2. the server use this key to decipher the cipher key of the file store in **files_keys**.
3. cipher key of the file is cipher with the derivate key of user password --> **PROBLEM HERE** because when need the password of dest user to encrypt this...
   --> Solution : Use public key of other user to cipher le file key.
4. store this(3) in **files_keys** table (with id of the new user).

Table **files**:

- UUID
- Filename
- Type
- Owner (UUID)

Table **files_keys**:

- UUID
- File (UUID)
- User (UUID) --> to know who encrypt the cipher key
- Cipher key --> Cipher key use to encrypt the file and cipher by the derivate key of user password

Do you have other ideas to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you consider [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) for this scenario?

Comment: For the access management who has read/write ability I think you can't do other than trust the server. On the server you can have all the users' public keys and for every file store a digest of the client side symmetrically encrypted file signed by the original authors private key. Then if you want to share the file just send him the symmetric key you used.  For the server to allow rediting the file one should be able to provide the correct signature of the file.

Comment: However this isn't really efficient for the server cause he will only be able to compare the two digests after receiving the file (before storing it), which can cause denial of service attacks. So you can replace this with some kind of authentication to the server before updating a file. What do you think?